# Variance in central limit theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

Why is it that $\sqrt{n}(X_{n}-\mu)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ but $\sqrt{n}(X_{n}-\mu)/\sigma$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{n}(X_{n}-\mu)/\sigma^2$?

Comment: Because $\text{var}(kX) = k^2 \text{var}(X)$ ?

Comment: I think you mean $\bar X_n$ (i.e., the sample mean), not $X_n$ (the $n$th observation

Comment: @gung, no, I believe it the denominator is correct as stated

Comment: @rvl There are no explicit statements about sampling here. Therefore we may, and should, take $X_n$ to be *any* sequence of random variables satisfying the stated convergence assumption. The usual setting (as suggested by the [tag:central-limit-theorem] tag) is that $X_n$ is the mean of $n$ iid variables from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: True. My comment was based on the most conventional notations, and imputing the independence assumption since that is an instance of when the given statements are true.

Answer (score 3):

**Change the units of measurement.**

For instance if $X_n$ is measured in meters, use a rod $\sigma$ meters long to measure $X_n$. Let's call the new unit an "sm."  That changes $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)$ meters into $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)/\sigma$ sms.  The former converges to $N(0\text{ meter},\sigma^2\text{ meter}^2)$ which, in the new measurement system, is $N(0\text{ sm},1\text{ sm}^2)$.  Therefore  $\sqrt{n}(X_n-\mu)/\sigma$  must converge to $N(0,1)$.